# Jquery mobile- Change content color of collapsible list

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to change the content color of a collapsile list.
Here is an example:
[image]

As you can see I have a collapsible list with a table and 2 ohter collapsible elements. I would like to have the outer collapsible list to be lightgray as shown, but the collapsible elements inside it should have the content white (like data-content-theme="a").
In order to have it lightgray I did so:

```
.ui-collapsible-themed-content .ui-collapsible-content {
    background-color: lightgray;
 }
```

but in this way all collapsible elements have the content gray..

Another way would be to make a custom theme with Theme Roller of JQuery, I did it but then the collapsible elements become gigantic (more than double):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to affect collapsible content that is within a parent collapsible, you can try this CSS:

```
.ui-collapsible-content .ui-collapsible-content {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lhfffcm5/)**

Another way could be to assign a class to all child collapsibles

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" class="childCollapsible">
```

And then use that class in the CSS:

```
.childCollapsible .ui-collapsible-content {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lhfffcm5/1/)**